# List vs Dictionary vs Class vs DataFrame in Python Data Formatting

Tags: list, python-3.x, class, dictionary, dataframe

I have a Python list made up of strings that contain property addresses and multiple attributes of each property.

```
'Date of Sale', 'January 1, 2017', 'Phone Number', '111-344-2343', 'Color', 'Brown', 'Garage Size', '2', 'Date Listed', 'September 23, 2016', 'Loan From', 'Example Mortgage Services', 'Street Address', '751 Example Drive', 'City', 'Chicago', 'Number of Windows', 'Attorney', 'Shaping LLP', 'Township', 'Dundee', 'Zip Code', '99999', 'List Price', '$83,301.87', 'Bid Amount', '$110,199.00', 'Miscellaneous', 'Long Driveway', 'Date of Sale', ...
```

This is one "entry". The list continues in the same pattern through the rest of the properties (each starts with 'Date of Sale'), though if fields are left empty they are skipped completely. For example, if a bid was not made 'Bid Amounts' is followed directly by 'Miscellaneous', rather than the amount.

The goal is to be able to easily parse the information. For example, I would like to list all of the properties that I have not bid on.

The primary question is what data format to use (`class`, list, dictionary, or dataframe):

```
class Property(object):
    def __init__(self,dateOfSale,phoneNumber...):
        self.dateOfSale = 'dateOfSale'
        self.phoneNumber = 'phoneNumber'
        ...
```

but I'm unsure how I would utilize this to get information on multiple properties.

OR

Combine all information about each property into one `list` item. I'm not sure how you would look through this info though.

OR

Use a `dictionary` by the Address the key, and all the other information the value, though that doesn't seem easily iterated upon either.

OR

Utilize a Pandas `dataframe`. I will have to do more research, but it seems like "spreadsheetable" data works well in that format.

Comment: Your example data seem to have an error: There's no value associated with the `"Number of Windows"` key. That's likely to break any parsing you attempt on it.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Blckknght I should have added better commenting. Some of the entries do not contain values associated with them, even though there is a key. If any field does not have an answer (in this case "windows"), the next item in the list will simply be the next key. Ultimately, the goal is to be able to find all of the addresses in the list that do not have a value for one of the keys.

Answer (score 2):

The current structure of your data is very awkward, so I'd suggest that you start by breaking it up and making a dictionary for each of your entries. You can later process the list of dictionaries into another more sophisticated data structure (like a `DataFrame`), but it's much easier to do the low-level processing first.

Here's how you can convert your single long list of strings into a list of of dicts:

```
raw_data = ['Date of Sale', 'January 1, 2017',
            'Phone Number', '111-344-2343',
            'Color', 'Brown',
            'Garage Size', '2',
            'Date Listed', 'September 23, 2016',
            'Loan From', 'Example Mortgage Services',
            'Street Address', '751 Example Drive',
            'City', 'Chicago',
            'Number of Windows', '16', # the value was missing for this key, so I made up one
            'Attorney', 'Shaping LLP',
            'Township', 'Dundee',
            'Zip Code', '99999',
            'List Price', '$83,301.87',
            'Bid Amount', '$110,199.00',
            'Miscellaneous', 'Long Driveway',
            'Date of Sale', ...] # this is data for two entries (the second is abbreviated)

list_of_dicts = []
for key, value in zip(*[iter(raw_data)]*2): # iterate on pairs of items from the raw list
    if key == "Date of Sale":
        current_dict = {}  # create a new dict each time we come across a Date of Sale key
        list_of_dicts.append(current_dict)
    current_dict[key] = value
```

I'm not at all experienced with Pandas, but I suspect you can make a dataframe from the list of dicts pretty easily (maybe just by passing the list as an argument to the `DataFrame` constructor, I'm not sure). You might need to pass extra arguments describing all the columns you expect your data to contain, especially if not all entries have values for all columns.

Comment: Thank you. How would you deal with the missing values?

Comment: Oh, I thought that when you said some values were missing you meant that both the key and value would not be included if there was no data for that key. If it's just the value that's missing, my approach above with `zip` on a repeated iterator won't work at all. You'd need to know all the names of your keys ahead of time, and check if each value is instead the name of the next key. It's really messy. Do you have any control over how the list is being generated? If you're parsing something, you might be able to fix the situation at an earlier point where it's less difficult.

Comment: What about something like this?
`list_of_dicts = []
for key, value in zip(*[iter(raw_data)]*2): # iterate on pairs of items from the raw list
    if key == "Date of Sale":
        current_dict = {}  # create a new dict each time we come across a Date of Sale key
    if value == "Date of Sale" or "Phone Number" or "Color" or "Garage Size"... #abbreviating the rest of the keys:
        value = '' #How do I continue the iteration with next key, rather than skipping it and getting out of order?
        list_of_dicts.append(current_dict)
    current_dict[key] = value`

Answer (score 0):

I would not go with Pandas DataFrame unless you actually need to do data analysis (KISS principle). I would probably use a list of namedtuple rather than of dict because it is cleaner syntactically, e.g.:

```
import csv
from collections import namedtuple
Property = namedtuple('Property', 'date_of_sale phone_number ...')

properties = []
with open('propertydata.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    for record in csv.reader(csvfile):
         properties.append(Property(*record))
```

Then you can iterate through properties and do whatever you need:

```
no_bid_properties = [p for p in properties where not p.bid_amount]
```